# Django - how to capture the selection user has made on frontend

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a dashboard and want to update the graphs based on selection user makes. For example if a user selects company A and click on button 'Update', the code captures that change, query data based on new selection and pass it on again to frontend.

I have been able to write most of the code where I can query database based on the selection. But I'm not sure how to capture the user selection and pass on to views.py from the frontend.

Models:

```
class Airline(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)

class FinancialData(models.Model): # All units in millions
    airline = models.ForeignKey(Airline)
    financial_year = models.ForeignKey(Year)
    mainline_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    regional_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    other_revenue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

Views.py:

```
class ListAirlineYearFinancialData(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FinancialDataSerializer
    airline_id = Airline.objects.filter(pk=1) # pk=1 is just a placeholder, but want to change based on selection
    queryset = FinancialData.objects.filter(airline_id=airline_id)
    queryset_filtered = queryset.filter(financial_year_id=1)


    def airline_dashboard(request):
        airline_list = Airline.objects.all() 
        year_list = Year.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'dashboard/company_page.html', {'airline_list': airline_list, 'year_list': year_list})

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset_filtered
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.ListAirlineYearFinancialData.airline_dashboard, name='airline_dashboard'),
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
 <select>
    {% for airline in airline_list %}
        <option>  
            Primary Key:  {{ airline.pk }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
 <select>
    {% for year in year_list %}
        <option> 
            Year: {{ year.year }}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
 <input type="button" value="Update">
</form>
```

Here is the screenshot of the web page:
[image]

Basically, I want to make this code line in Views.py to change based on the selection by user: `airline_id = Airline.objects.filter(pk=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use some ajax to avoid page refresh.

**Here's how it should work :** When user clicks on update, then a POST request will be sent to server through ajax and it will filter depending the user's selection.

**Ajax JS** send POST request to your view :

```
$(document).on('click', '#your_update_button', function(e){
    var form_data = new FormData($('#your_form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/your_url/',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data : form_data,
        success: function(response) {
           #get your json
           respone.your_json_key

           #display to template ...
        }
    });
});
```

**Django, views.py** filters whatever you need and returns it in ajax success under JSON format

```
def updateData(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        identifier = request.POST.get('your_selection_choice')
        airline_id = Airline.objects.filter(pk=identifier)
        serialized_airline_id = serializers.serialize('json', airline_id)
        json_airline_id = json.loads(serialized_airline_id)

        return JsonResponse(data={
            'airline_id' : json_airline_id,
        })
    return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

I'm not using class based views but that'll give you an idea on how you can build what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lindow for the direction. You are awesome!